# How to strip or slice the bottom items of a SplHeap (also SplMaxHeap, SplMinHeap)?

Tags: php, heap, slice, spl

I have a [`SplMaxHeap`](http://php.net/splmaxheap) with 30 items. Now I want to strip the last 10 ones. How to do this in a decent and efficient way?

The only solutions I see so far is to copy the first 20 items to a new heap or to [convert](http://php.net/iterator_to_array) the heap to an array, use the `array_slice` and put them also in a new heap.

I even can't see a way to get something out of the heap not from the top.

I guess the reason for this is a limitation of the general design of a heap? I was also thinking to use a [`DoublyLinkedList`](http://php.net/spldoublylinkedlist), however there I am missing the automatic sorting.

Comment: @PaulCrovella I see and understand. I just hope someone finds a clever way to work around this design limitation. If there is no good answer, I know at least that I don't have to try it and that I have to use a custom data structure.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to create a new class derived from an SPL heap, which upon insert only keeps the top (or bottom, depending on the heap) *n* items.

A super-basic example might look something like:

```
class Top100 extends SplMinHeap
{
    protected $limit = 100;
    public function insert($value)
    {
        parent::insert($value);
        while (count($this) > $this->limit) {
            $this->extract();
        }
    }
}
```

This is discussed further in Tobias Schlitt's 2010 article "[Heap, heap, hooray!](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0718_heap_heap_hooray.html)".

Comment: This has the problem that now you cannot extract the top anymore, unless you take them all, and reverse them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that inside a SPLHeap there is no "bottom". Elements are stored in a tree-like structure. The term "bottom" becomes a bit meaningless, however, there is always a "top" of the tree, and this is exactly what SPLHeap can return.

If you have a small number of items, you might get away with alternative data structures (even simple arrays would suffice). Inserting elements might take a bit extra time (this is where trees are much efficient), but maintaining a top and bottom is cheap again (like the `SplDoubleLinkedList`).

Unless you are storing tens of thousands of elements, you might want to skip the SplHeap for this.

Note: it's trivial enough to create a fixedHeap structure in PHP itself, but i reckon it would not be faster. Benchmark to check what satisfies your needs.